# XNA - Embed DirectX control in a form?

Tags: winforms, xna

I want to render DirectX (well, XNA) stuff to a system.windows.forms control rather than the whole window (so I can pair it with buttons and stuff).

Is this possible? Which control would I use? How would I do it? I've searched the documentation but I don't know which terms I'm meant to use!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. There's a [sample](http://creators.xna.com/en-US/sample/winforms_series1) that does just this.