# With Winforms, how do I make a graphics pane that can be dragged, zoomed/unzoomed, and items inside selected?

Tags: .net, winforms, user-interface

I'm using C# and .net 3.5 to make a Winforms application.

I need to have a pane that displays a tree of connected geometric items. I want to be able to click-drag to move the view around, use the mouse wheel to zoom in and out, and click to select the items.

I can see that it would be possible to code all this using a pictureBox and a bunch of event processing and math. I'm not against doing this. But if there is a pre-existing solution for this (or even a recommendation on a control better suited to the task), I would rather not have to go through all the trouble of writing this GUI stuff.

Comment: Possible duplicate. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577145/xna-embed-directx-control-in-a-form)

Comment: I was hoping for something like a 3rd-party control with built-in zoom and drag functions, but this looks like it's one way to do it.

Comment: Looks like I'm wrong about using PictureBox. MSDN says it cannot be the focus to receive input events.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the point of your application?

Comment: It's an external debugging application for an AI system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mentioned this earlier in a comment, but probably the best solution is to create a custom UserControl.  You can specifically handle the events that you want to handle (MouseDown, MouseMove, MouseUp, keyboard events, etc.).

Draw an image and set it as the Background to the control.  You can then add the control (or multiple controls!) to your form for your purpose.